# lazyloading ngTable using ocLazyLoad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable, angular-components, oclazyload

In one our projects we're trying to write a wrapper around ngTable library! in this component's controller, we're loading [ngTable](http://ng-table.com/) using [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad).
Here's what we've written:

#### Datagrid Component

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('CommonApplication')
    .component('datagrid', {
      scope: true,
      bindings: {
        basepath: '@',
        title: '@',
        dataset: '<'
      },
      templateUrl: '/frontend/components/global/datagrid/templates/datagrid.html',
      controller: 'DataGridController',
    });

})();
```

#### Datagrid Controller with $ocLazyLoad (Doesn't work :~| )

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('CommonApplication')
    .controller('DataGridController', 
    [ '$scope', '$injector', '$ocLazyLoad', DataGridController ]);

  function DataGridController($scope, $injector, $ocLazyLoad) {

    var vm = this;
    var components = {
      datagrid: [
        'https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.2.0/bundles/ng-table.min.css',
        'https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.2.0/bundles/ng-table.min.js'
      ]
    };

    $ocLazyLoad.load(components.datagrid).then(function() {
      var NgTableParams = $injector.get('NgTableParams');
      vm.data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},{name: "Moroni", age: 50},{name: "Moroni", age: 50},{name: "Moroni", age: 50}];
      vm.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 10
      }, {
        dataset: vm.data
      });
    });
  }

})();
```

#### Datagrid Controller without $ocLazyLoad (Works)

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('CommonApplication')
    .controller('DataGridController', 
    [ '$scope', '$injector', '$ocLazyLoad', DataGridController ]);

  function DataGridController($scope, $injector, $ocLazyLoad) {

    var vm = this;
    var components = {
      datagrid: [
        'https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.2.0/bundles/ng-table.min.css',
        'https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.2.0/bundles/ng-table.min.js'
      ]
    };

    var NgTableParams = $injector.get('NgTableParams');
    vm.data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},{name: "Moroni", age: 50},{name: "Moroni", age: 50},{name: "Moroni", age: 50}];
    vm.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
      page: 1,
      count: 10
    }, {
      dataset: vm.data
    });
  }

})();
```

Using ocLazyLoad, If I set a breakpoint on the line that we're defining `vm.tableParams` when it get populated by `new NgTableParams` the settings and other properties of it have this particular error in their `arguments` properties.

---

Here's the Exception Error which points to the end of `$ocLazyLoad.then` function callback! It's `datagrid.js:47:7` because we concat these js file and another one into `datagrid.js`:

```
TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context.
    at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:3:14)
    at http://localhost:8081/frontend/components/global/datagrid/datagrid.js:47:7
    at http://localhost:8081/frontend/javascripts/head.min.js:136:20
    at m.$eval (http://localhost:8081/frontend/javascripts/head.min.js:150:347)
    at m.$digest (http://localhost:8081/frontend/javascripts/head.min.js:147:420)
    at http://localhost:8081/frontend/javascripts/head.min.js:150:434
    at e (http://localhost:8081/frontend/javascripts/head.min.js:50:444)
    at http://localhost:8081/frontend/javascripts/head.min.js:53:300
```

---

**Any Thoughts on this?!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, lazy loading even using its promise `.then(callback)` doesn't make Angular wait for its completion!

What I was doing is to initialize a table using `ngTableParams` when loading of `ng-table` finishes! With this on mind, I decided to use a simple trick!

I attached ngTableParams to a Scope variable called `vm.tableParams` which later I will use to initialize the table in the view with it right when using `ng-table`'s directive. So even before calling the directive which hasn't been loaded yet we check if the lazy loading is completed or not using `ng-if` and `tableParams`:

#### View: *datagrid.pug*

```
// Load Directive if Params in the controller were attached to the scope!
.row.expanded(ng-if="table.tableParams")
    .small-12.columns 
      table.data-table.hover.stacktable.table-condensed.table-bordered.table-striped(ng-table-dynamic="table.tableParams with table.headers",template-pagination="custom/pager", show-filter="true")
        tr(ng-repeat="(rowIndex, row) in $data ")
          td(ng-repeat="column in $columns", ng-switch="column.field")
            input.selectSwitch( ng-switch-when="selector", type="checkbox", ng-model="table.checkboxes.items[row.id]") 
            div(ng-switch-when="id") {{ rowIndex + 1 }}
            div(ng-switch-when="body") {{ row }}
            span(ng-switch-default) {{row[column.field]}}
```

#### Controller: *datagrid.controller.js*

```
// Lazyload datagrid components and Initialize headers and parametres!
    $ocLazyLoad.load(components.datagrid).then(function (){
      self.headers = self.dataset.headers;
      self.dataset.headers.forEach(function( header ) {
        header.title = header.headerTitle;
      });
      var NgTableParams = $injector.get('NgTableParams');
      self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
        count: 5
      }, {
        dataset: self.dataset.data
      });
    });
```

---

This way we won't be using `$compile` manually to re-render the view and we let angular handle the compilation itself, not affecting the Performance :)